# It's possible to make XTERM and Gnome-keyring work together?

Tags: ubuntu, xterm, gnome-terminal

When I'am connecting to ssh with **gnome-terminal** application opens gnome-keyring dialog, so I am entering password only once per session and I can reconnect to same ssh more than once without asking the password.

But this doesn't work in xterm. Maybe someone can help to make this work?

Comment: How *exactly* do you start gnome-terminal and xterm? Did you do any setup to be able to use gnome-keyring? What OS/distribution are you running?

Answer (score 2):

Are you running xterm from inside your Gnome session as well?

Try this in Gnome Terminal:

```
echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

Then try the same in xterm.

It should print something like

```
/tmp/keyring-abc123/ssh
```

in both.

I'm guessing it doesn't print something like that in xterm.

If it's empty, something is clearing it (or not setting it).

If looks more like

```
/tmp/ssh-defgh67890/agent
```

then you are also running ssh-agent somewhere, which will get confusing.

Here's what I'd try:

Run `echo $0` in both.  Does one have `-` at the start and the other not?

If so, you are probably running ssh-agent in login shells, but not non-login shells.  Have a look in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` or equivalent scripts and fix the problem.

Or change whether xterm is started as a login shell:

1. using `xterm*loginShell: true` or `xterm*loginShell: false` in your `~/.Xdefaults` or `~/.xresources`?
2. by running `xterm -ls` or `xterm` (without `-ls`)

Copy the setting you have for Gnome Terminal under Profile Preferences->Title and Command->Run command as a login shell.

If that fails, try adding `echo` statements in your startup files.  You'll need to redirect the output to a log file using `echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK >> ~/ssh-debug.log` or similar.

Then log out and back in, and have a look at your `~/ssh-debug.log`.

Then run Gnome Terminal and look at it again.

Then run xterm and look and look at it again.

Look for differences.

Have a look at /etc/pam.d/gdm and System->Preferences->Startup Applications.  Do you have any other ssh-agent configuration anywhere in /etc/pam.d?

Have a look `/etc/X11/Xsession` and the scripts that it calls.

Comment: When I `echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK` in xterm I've got: `/tmp/ssh-mIDzpMya1902/agent.1902`. In gnome-terminal: `/tmp/keyring-F5L0Fh/ssh`. If I set `export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/keyring-F5L0Fh/ssh` then xterm works with gnome-keyring. What should I do to set this value in xterm (this value should be the same as in gnome terminal, but every new terminal window this value changes)?

Comment: As I have explained, you will need to look at your own setup, because it is different from mine.  Look at your `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile` to start with and see if they contain `ssh-agent`.  If not, look at `/etc/pam.d` and `/etc/X11/Xsession`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also have a look at the workaround given at [Red Hat Bugzilla - Bug 713955 - SSH_AUTH_SOCK environment variable not present in terminals launched via keyboard shortcut](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=713955#c4) by adding this to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
#GPG and SSH agent not exported when running terminal by shortcut
if [ -z "$GPG_AGENT_INFO" -a -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" -a -n "$GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL" ] ; then
        #derive GPG and SSH agent info from GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL
        export GPG_AGENT_INFO="$GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL/gpg:0:1"
        export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="$GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL/ssh"
fi
```

In my case (Centos 6 with gnome 2.28), the `GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL` variable does not exist (but `GNOME_KEYRING_SOCKET` does), and the gnome keyring "seahorse" does not seem to provide GPG_AGENT_INFO.

So I ended up with this version (also placed in `~/.bashrc`):

```
set_keyring_agent() {
# SSH agent not exported when running terminal by shortcut
# see https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=713955#c4
# and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11355/its-possible-to-make-xterm-and-gnome-keyring-work-together
if [[ -n "${GNOME_KEYRING_SOCKET}" && -z "${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}" ]] ; then
  #derive SSH agent info from GNOME_KEYRING_SOCKET
  local ssh_auth_socket="${GNOME_KEYRING_SOCKET}.ssh"
  if [[ -S "${ssh_auth_socket}" ]] ; then
    export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="${ssh_auth_socket}"
  fi
fi
}

set_keyring_agent
```

Answer (score 0):

While I didn't figure out what magic makes gnome-terminal get the correct SSH_AUTH_SOCK from gnome-keyring-daemon, I found a workaround to set the correct value in XTerm (or other terminals).  Add the following to your .bashrc:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=`netstat -xl | grep -o '/tmp/keyring-.*/ssh$'`
[ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] || export SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

What this does: it looks for a local listening socket which has a name matching the pattern "/tmp/keyring-*/ssh", and sets the value of SSH_AUTH_SOCK to that, if it's present.

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10786874#post10786874